# Can't get PHP string variable to expand

Tags: php, argument-passing

I define a string variable like this:

```
$menu = '../views/menus/documentation-menu.html';
```

Later in the script I try to use it like so:

```
$content = file_get_contents("{$menu}");
```

But when I run the script, it warns me that "Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in ".

If fact, I've tried all sorts of combinations with double quotes and single quotes and no braces, but always wrong. If I put the string in directly, it works as expected:

```
    $content = file_get_contents("../views/menus/documentation-menu.html");
```

But I want $menu to be the argument to file_get_contents, not a hard-coded string.

I'm probably missing something very simple because I don't know PHP that well ....

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `$content = file_get_contents($menu);`?

That said, do you actually want to manipulate the file contents, or just include it in the page? If the latter, just use `include` or `require`.

Comment: Yes, tried that, and I get the same  "Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in ..." warning. I am manipulating the file contents, and the output is empty because of what that warning is saying: like it's not expanding the variable.

Comment: That should work...can you post a more full version of your script? Have you tried `var_dump($menu)` immediately before the `file_get_contents` call to check it's set correctly?